# "being moved to page file" event

Tags: c#, windows

Is there an event ( or similar ) in C# to tell when the current process is about to be moved from memory to the page file? Also for that matter an event for coming back from the pagefile.

Or if those events do not exist, perhaps a better way for this to happen or suggestions?

The reason i would like to accomplish this:
I have an application / inventory management program which allows you to look through everything and it mostly keeps all that information in a large List. I would like to just clear out that list before it gets written to disk. It just becomes stale information and slows down the return of the program when it has to be resumed. I would rather be querying the database for new information instead of loading stale info.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: When is a whole application ever moved to the page file? That's typically done by pages.

Comment: I guess everybody could benefit by some memory manager callbacks, telling you when it's time free up some memory, otherwise you get swapped out. But it's not that easy. You need to do some data access optimization, what's usually done: paging, do not load everything at once, cache the most accessed parts of your data (some of which may never become stale) and so on.

Comment: This is to my best understanding of how the page file works, which i could be wrong.
My program does need to handle pulling the appropriate data instead of all the dataz!
However that would be a program rewrite which I don't have the work time for that. (Just like all great workplace programs)

Comment: There's no such event, and there shouldn't be. It's the operating system's task to manage the swap pages, and your app should not be needing to know this is happening (which is probably why there's no such event). You're trying to kludge a solution, instead of properly fixing the actual problem. :-)

Comment: Even if you had such an event, it wouldn't be useful, because the GC is going to have to page the objects in to finalize them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is no such event.  Even if there were, memory is paged out at the, err, page level, and there is no easy way to know what objects reside in which pages.  Add to that the fact that even if you knew that object X is in page Y, X likely has references to other objects that may reside in other pages.  So even if X is currently paged in, actually using it may require paging in other memory.  And the garbage collector can move objects in memory over their lifetime, making the whole problem more complicated.

That said, for your use case it sounds like you shouldn't even be storing the data in a large List.  Can you just use normal data binding?

Comment: Great explanation as to why I shouldn't be trying to kludge together a soultion (trying to do this is much worse the I thought initally). I prolly will trim down my list of items and pull them as I need to query. 

I don't use direct binding to the database class objects as I do quite a bit of manipulation and changing / linking of the data I pull in. Then based on the list<class> I make bind to the display.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such event. However, if your program happens to be using ASP.Net then you can use [System.Web.Caching.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cache.aspx): it will dump your cached objects when there's memory pressure.

I don't know of a good one outside of ASP.Net, but perhaps someone else can suggest something?

**edit**: meklarian suggests trying out [System.Runtime.Caching](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd985642%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), probably specifically [MemoryCache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.runtime.caching.memorycache%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). Thank you meklarian!

Comment: System.Runtime.Caching is an alternative